# Azure - The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'Id' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure

i created mobile service at azure, and

when i do access to this URL = `http://home03.azure-mobile.net/tables/SignUp`

it give me an error like :

```
{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'Id' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind."}
```

Comment: Having similar issue. Did you find the cause?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750227/where-clause-returning-the-query-specified-in-the-uri-is-not-valid