# Where() clause returning "The query specified in the URI is not valid..."

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have a .Net mobile service.

Calling this:

https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/tables/items?$filter=(company%20eq%20%27987af3f9-8d44-4a9d-8be2-7e0567287106%27)

Returns:

> {"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not
>   find a property named 'company' on type
>   'Default.<>f__AnonymousType2_3OfString_String_Double'."}

The field name in the "items" entity model is "company" and on the database is "company_Id", neither will work.

Using http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js

What could be wrong?

Comment: I tried connecting to your mobile service, and I saw there was a name property in the json. However, when I tried to filter on it, I saw the same issue. Can you post the definition of your model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that you can only filter a field that is present in the $select clause. As said [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4e91f18a-65bd-46fc-a799-45ea5b742b46/where-clause-returning-the-query-specified-in-the-uri-is-not-valid?forum=azuremobile)
Doesn't make sense but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you are running into a casing bug in the .NET backend when $select or $filter is used. The workaround is to use Pascal case (i.e., uppercase first letter) for your property names.

Answer (score 0):

Having the first character as lower case for my column names prevented me from querying my Azure database with LINQ or Lambda expressions.

Switching them to upper case letters did the trick.